# Des cas où la prononciation attendue diffère de la phonologie des graphèmes/phonèmes rattachés aux lettres restantes avec l'apostrophe ?

Tags: prononciation, oral, phonétique

L'apostrophe peut « indiquer que certaines lettres sont escamotées lorsqu’on veut imiter la langue parlée » ([BDL](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/23349/la-ponctuation/autres-signes-graphiques/apostrophe)) ; ceci peut même inclure un espace, par exemple « aut’chose » (*autre chose*).

Connaît-on des cas en français, incidemment même quand elle représente l'élision, où la prononciation attendue de telles imitations de la langue parlée diffère de la phonologie des graphèmes et phonèmes correspondants rattachés aux lettres restantes (par exemple « c'bon » prononcé /sebɔ̃/ plutôt que /sbɔ̃/) voire une pause à l'intérieur d'un mot ou groupe de mots (« c'héros » pour « ce héros » ou « l'héros » pour « le/les héros ») ?

Comment: Tu penses-tu aux rébus ?

Answer (score 1):

"*Le Bon Usage*" donne un échantillons de plusieurs sortes d'utilisations de l'apostrophe pour les sons escamotés.

(*caractères gras dus à user LPH*)

> (**LBU § 45**) l'Ac. 2001 accepte aussi la graphie avec apostrophe
> (**s'ENTR'aimer**, etc.).

> (**LBU § 107**)
>
> Les auteurs utilisent parfois l'apostrophe afin de rendre le langage
> populaire (ou jugé tel) pour d'autres amuïssements de e que l'élision ou pour
> des amuïssements d'autres sons.
> • Mais **j'vais** me revenger. GENET, Notre-Dame-des-Fleurs, p. 169).
> • **l's'soûle** et laisse ses enfants crever **d'faim** (GIDE, Souvenirs de la cour d'ass., V).
> • Des beaux céleris, **m'ame** [= madame] Cointreau (FRANCE, Crainquebille, VI).
> • Pardon, **m'dame** (SABATIER, Trois sucettes à la menthe, p. 67).
> • **'tais** [= J'étais] avec des copains (IKOR, Tourniquet des innocents, p. 50).
> • La jeunesse d'asteur sait pas ça. **A'** [= elle] regimbe (A. MAILLET, Sagouine, p. 59).
>
> Parfois dans la poésie et souvent dans la chanson, l'apostrophe indique que l'e muet ne forme pas un pied — et ne reçoit pas de note.
> • Si tous les gars du monde voulaient bien **êtr'** marins, ils **f'raient** avec leurs barques un joli pont sur l'onde (P. FORT, Ballades franç., Ronde autour du monde).
> •  Et dans mon âme il brûle encore / A la **manier'** d'un feu de joie (G. BRASSENS, Chanson pour l'Auvergnat).
> Certains utilisent l'apostrophe pour le phénomène lexical de la réduction
> (§ 188)
> •  La **Maub'** [= la place Maubert] (SANDRY et CARRÈRE, Dict. de l'argot
> moderne, s. v. Maub').
> • Tous les **prof's** (Cl. SIMON, Sacre du printemps, L. P., p. 23).

Comment: @viande-à-chien … mets tes commentaires plutôt dans ta question, c'l'a précisera :-)

Comment: @viande-à-chien J'ai eu du mal à lire la question, mais maintenant je comprends mieux; ne rien effacer, ainsi  je peux  relire, occasionnellement, comme le pourront d'autres s'ils sont intéressés.